# Multiple OR with an array input Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to chain multiple OR conditions. Right now I am chaining them like a string. But I have around 10-20 values I want to check for `NULL` with an `OR` clause.

This works:

```
Model.where("foo is NULL OR bar is NULL")
```

But I would rather have something like (pseudo code):

```
Model.where("[:foo, :bar] IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord doesn't support chaining 'OR' out of the box, but it's not very difficult in your case:

```
fields = %w{foo bar}
Model.where(fields.map{|f| "#{f} IS NULL"}.join(" OR "))
```

You can even extract this to a reusable method if you find you need this often:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    class << self
      def any_null(fields)
        where(fields.map{|f| "#{quote_column_name f} IS NULL"}.join(" OR "))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can call:

```
Model.any_null(w%{foo bar})
```

Naturally this doesn't support automatic tablename resolution, but it should do the trick for most cases.